# Which Ktor method is correct -- append() or buildPacket()?

Tags: android, kotlin, http, ktor

I'm trying to upload an image file to a server and have been using this method to "append" the binary file bytes to the message. 'srcBitmap' is a byteArray containing the image bytes.

```
    formData = formData {
        append("image", srcBitmap, Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/jpg")
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=image.jpg")
                })
```

In other examples on the web they do it this way.

```
    formData {
        appendInput(key = ICON_FILE_PART, headers = Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${appId}_ic")
        }) {
            buildPacket { writeFully(icon.toByteArray()) }
        }
    })
```

What's the difference between these two ways (append vs. 'buildPacket')? Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

These are just different ways of making multipart binary parts. Using `buildPacket` you can build arbitrary byte packets with no knowledge of their size. If you need to create a binary part from a file then I recommend using the first option because it's straightforward and easier to understand.